# How to email reports created by ReportNG using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, testng, reportng

How to email the reports created by ReportNG using Jenkins?

I have done ReportNG set-up which is perfectly giving the reports to me and I have integrated my suite with Jenkins. But I don't know how to send the reports created by ReportNg as mail via Jenkins. Because, only if we have the entire html folder, the ReportNG works and able to see html report since there are dependencies in the ReportNG so I have to zip and send the entire html folder to see the perfect result.

Note : I am using Emailable-Ext plugin in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the report links from your jenkins server where the reports are saved. And just email the link to the stakeholders, instead of emailing entire report.
Also, you can try jenkins plugins to automatically move the reports to some other machine/directory for future purpose (if needed) and email the links.